# Autohotkey interacting with Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, autohotkey, microsoft-edge

I'm brand new to autohotkey. I would like to make a script that fills out a form in a webbrowser. Since Firefox is my browser of choice, I would prefer to use it. However, preliminary research has given me doubt as to whether Firefox works with autohotkey. For example I found [this thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/49036-there-is-a-solution-to-write-scripts-for-firefox/) which seems to suggest autohotkey can't properly interact with firefox. What is the situation? My understanding is DOM must be used to fill in a form, which IE supports. So must IE be used with autohotkey?

My target platform is Windows 10 64bit and preferable Firefox, else Internet Explorer (or Edge). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might have some luck with the `pyautogui` module on Python 3...

Comment: Did you ask this on that autohotkey board?

Comment: @Rob it would appear the autohokey board is closed for registration

Answer (score 1):

FireFox doesn't have an open COM interface like Ie.

You can do things manually speaking using send, hotkeys and mouseclick commands, but in some cases this will be unreliable.

`Run, Firefox.exe URL` works to open a specific page, as it does in Chrome as well.

There is probably another way that is more advanced, but I have not discovered it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate form filling with autohotkey and firefox you're going to have a rough time. Very little in firefox shows up as a manipulatable control. It's possible to make scripts that send `tab` to move between text fields and `enter` to to press a button if you can tab to it. You can also do imagesearch for the appearance of button and use page up/down to scroll through a form. To be clear, your mouse moves, keyboard input, etc will still be acknowledged by firefox, it's just unlike most other standard windows programs you won't be able to interact with the controls directly using the robust ControlSend, ControlGet.

If you need to gather text automatically from a website in firefox, it's possible to save the page and parse the html.

But again, this is not the best way of doing this. You can fine tune it until it works, but if you are just starting AHK and you want primarily do browser automation, there are better options.

Answer (score 1):

Edge example:
realy simple manipulate DOM and get feedback from page like this:

```
        Send, ^`` ; goto console
        Send, ^l ; clear console
        Send, ^+{Home}{Del} ; remove all text in console
        Send, copy(document.getElementById("flash_messages").innerText){Enter}
        if (Clipboard != "zzz"){
            break
        }
```

do this for Firefox not so hard..

Answer (score 0):

I would try out Selenium.  It works pretty well with Chrome but it is supposed to work with FireFox as well.